# Laravel programatically calling artisan command from web.php in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.6

I have below route:

```
Route::get('/beneficiaries/seed', function () {
    echo "<p>Database seeding started...</p>";
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('db:seed');
    echo "<p>Database seeding completed.</p>";
});
```

In my local environment, when I visit '/beneficiaries/seed', it seeds the database. But if I do the same in production, it doesn't. I just copied the seeder classes and route file.

**DatabaseSeeder:**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(BeneficiariesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**BeneficiariesTableSeeder:**

```
class BeneficiariesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        //seeding logic...
    }
}
```

Why my production Artisan command doesn't get executed? (I haven't used database transaction. Even w/o it, local db gets seeded since there is no err is raised.)

Comment: Seeding in `production` environment is "secured" I guess, have you tried running your artisan command via CLI in a `production` environment?

Comment: This is kind of a staging environment, so that, I do not have shell access to my production server. :(

Comment: Did you tried to check your log file in your stg environment?

Comment: Yes and there is nothing in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `php artisan db:seed` in production, there is a warning that asks you whether you're sure to seed the database in production.

This warning confirmation in production is the reason why `Artisan::call('db:seed')` isn't working in production.

To circumvent the warning, you can use the `--force` flag like so: `php artisan db:seed --force`.

**Solution**

To do the same in code, use `Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--force' => true]);`

Comment: Great technical answer, but IMO the real answer here is probably "gah! don't do that!" I wouldn't want a Google crawl of my site to inadvertently seed it with a bunch of data.

Comment: Completely agree @ceejayoz it's generally a bad practice to do this in production, but can't say much until we know more. Perhaps there's a middleware to avoid only certain "admin" role users to do this. Or perhaps, this route is IP whitelisted for a certain other app to call under "critical" circumstances

Comment: Thanks and I'll try this solution tonight and come back. (Y)